# android adding DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION in release build

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, android-13

After building my application with api-level 33, android is adding new permission in the merged manifest

```
    <permission android:name="com.my.package.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"/>
```

I have a broadcast receiver, is this permission have anything to do with this?
should I change any code? Does anybody know the reason this has been added?

````
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.my.package.EventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.my.package.event"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```
````

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From https://developer.android.google.cn/about/versions/13/features#runtime-receivers:

> ##### Safer exporting of context-registered receivers
>
> To help make runtime receivers safer, Android 13 introduces the ability for your app to specify whether a [registered broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers) should be exported and visible to other apps on the device. On previous versions of Android, any app on the device could send an unprotected broadcast to a dynamically-registered receiver unless that receiver was guarded by a [signature permission](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/topics/permissions/overview#signature).
>
> This exporting configuration is available on apps that do at least one of the following:
>
> - Use the [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat) class from version 1.9.0 or higher of the [AndroidX Core library](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx/releases/core).
> - Target Android 13 or higher.

This node in AndroidManifest.xml is a configuration for [Safer exporting of context-registered receivers](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers), [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat) needs to use this permission to handle broadcast receiver.

Once the necessary conditions are met, it can be used like this.For more details, please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers)

Adding dependencies in Gradle.

```
dependencies {
    val core_version = "1.9.0"
    implementation("androidx.core:core:$core_version")
}
```

In app code:

```
// Create an instance of BroadcastReceiver.
val br: BroadcastReceiver = MyBroadcastReceiver()
// Create an instance of IntentFilter.
val filter = IntentFilter(APP_SPECIFIC_BROADCAST)
// Choose whether the broadcast receiver should be exported and visible to other apps on the device. If this receiver is listening for broadcasts sent from the system or from other apps—even other apps that you own—use the RECEIVER_EXPORTED flag. If instead this receiver is listening only for broadcasts sent by your app, use the RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag.
val listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps = false
val receiverFlags = if (listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps) {
    ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
} else {
    ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
}
// Register the receiver by calling registerReceiver():
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, br, filter, receiverFlags)
```

---

If you don't need to use this feature and want to remove this node in AndroidManifest.xml, you can do so:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"         
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Write the above code to AndroidManifest.xml, DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION will **be removed when the manifest is merged**

Comment: Could you explain how this relates to the permission automatically added to the manifest? (And please mark clearly what is a quote from the Android website.)

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question and why this is marked as correct. Does anyone know what is the use of DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION permission and why is it added automatically by the core libray?

Comment: If the Android version is less than 33 and the receiver has RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag, this permission is used to block broadcasts from system or other apps.

Comment: How come I can't find any documentation about DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION  ? I don't even understand when it's used. I got a crash on Crashlytics related to this, that it failed to start a service inside the app: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/291834495 . I don't understand what I'm supposed to add, and why

Comment: In the question the receiver is "Manifest receiver" how the hell the solution is for context registered receiver?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is looking for some additional information about the `DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION` here is what I found.

It's tied to the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` library and appears to be how they implement the flags `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED` and `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED` flags when using `ContextCompat.registerReceiver()`

I am not sure which version of the library introduced the flags, but `1.6.1` does have them (`1.5.1` does not). As long as your app has the library dependency with these flags the permission will get added regardless of using `ContextCompat.registerReceiver()` or not.